# Remove empty properties from JSON

Tags: marklogic

I would like to remove every empty (e.g. "a" = "") JSON properties
from instance section inside the envelope.
I wrote the code like below, but it does not working.
Could anyone advise me how to make this work?

```
let doc = fn.doc(URI);

function cleanProp(doc) {
  for (var propName in doc) { 
    if (doc[propName] === null || doc[propName] === undefined || doc[propName] === "") {
      delete doc[propName];
    }
  }
}

cleanProp(doc);
```

Comment: I tried and its working whats wrong? what is the value of doc?

Comment: URI is actual document's uri, like /testdata/aaa.json which consists of general envelope pattern headers.

Comment: it will be same like this let doc = {"a":"","b":"1"};?

Comment: Actually like this, {"envelope":{"headers":[], "triples":[], "instance":{"A":"22", "B":""} }; I would like to clear entire B properties from this JSON.

Comment: oh thats why. I got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. hope it helps

NOTE: It's only works for the given variables if you're looking for dynamic looping you can you Recursive looping.

```js
let doc =  {"envelope":{"headers":[], "triples":[], "instance":{"A":"22", "B":""} }};

function cleanProp(doc) {
  for (var propName in doc) { 
   for(var d in doc[propName]){
      if (!isEmpty(doc[propName][d]) || doc[propName][d].length != 0) {

         for (var f in doc[propName][d]){
            if (doc[propName][d][f] === null || doc[propName][d][f] === undefined || doc[propName][d][f] === "") {
              delete doc[propName][d][f];
              }
         }
      }
    }
  }
}

cleanProp(doc);

console.log(doc);

function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var key in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```